# Add a cross-fade to a ProRes clip

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a ProRes 422 HQ trailer clip that is about 70 seconds. I would like to add a 0.5s cross fade (to black/silence) at the head and tail of the clip. The output file must have the exact same characteristics as the input file.

Where I'm starting at is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:??|trailer.mov|??" -c copy output.mov
```

Is there a way to do this with ProRes 422 in ffmpeg. If not, what other tools might work for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "fade=t=in:d=0.5,fade=t=out:d=0.5:start_time=69.5" -c:v prores -c:a copy output.mov
```

Comment: how do you add the black clip to fade into/out of at the start/end of things though?

Comment: @David542 I thought you wanted to fade in from black at the beginning and out to black at the end. Now I'm not really sure what you want to do.

Comment: yes, exactly. Does your solution already do that? If so, could you just point out which part adds the back, or does doing `fade=t=in` automatically imply black if nothing is there?

Comment: @David542 Yes, that's what my command does: `fade=t=in:d=0.5` adds the fade in to the beginning and `fade=t=out:d=0.5:start_time=69.5` to the end. Default color is black but you can change it if you prefer. See [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) docs.